# Use gdb to debug running Python programs，get 0x00007f1b8850ca66 in ?? ()'

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging the python program.  The program is running in the contains.

I used the `ps` to get the pid (server.py, 97).

```
ps -ef
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sn             1       0  0 00:18 ?        00:00:14 /home/sn/bin/runtime-manager
snuser        97       1  0 10:13 ?        00:01:03 /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/snuser/runtime/server.py 10.42.0.147:31607 10.42.0.147:31
```

I use gdb to debug it, command is `gdb python3.8 --pid 97`

I get the message '0x00007f1b8850ca66 in ?? ()'

```
Reading symbols from python3.8...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/46/26b2aa784f1d7eee14936ba441180e2824c1dd.debug...done.done.
Attaching to program: /usr/bin/python3.8, process 97
[New LWP 100]
[New LWP 101]
[New LWP 102]
[New LWP 103]
[New LWP 104]
[New LWP 105]
[New LWP 106]
[New LWP 107]
[New LWP 108]
[New LWP 109]
[New LWP 110]
[New LWP 111]
[New LWP 112]
[New LWP 113]
[New LWP 114]
[New LWP 115]
[New LWP 116]
[New LWP 117]
[New LWP 118]
0x00007f1b8850ca66 in ?? ()
```

And I use `py-bt`, get the message 'Unable to locate python frame'.

```
(gdb) py-bt
Unable to locate python frame
(gdb) py-list
Unable to locate gdb frame for python bytecode interpreter
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame
* 1    LWP 97 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b8850ca66 in ?? ()
  2    LWP 100 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b881db8c2 in ?? ()
  3    LWP 101 "default-executo" 0x00007f1b88505839 in ?? ()
  4    LWP 102 "resolver-execut" 0x00007f1b88505839 in ?? ()
  5    LWP 103 "grpc_global_tim" 0x00007f1b88505839 in ?? ()
  6    LWP 104 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  7    LWP 105 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b881db6d6 in ?? ()
  8    LWP 106 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b881db6d6 in ?? ()
  9    LWP 107 "ZMQbg/Reaper" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  10   LWP 108 "ZMQbg/IO/0" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  11   LWP 109 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b884febf9 in ?? ()
  12   LWP 110 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b8850cbd7 in ?? ()
  13   LWP 111 "ZMQbg/Reaper" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  14   LWP 112 "ZMQbg/IO/0" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  15   LWP 113 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b884febf9 in ?? ()
  16   LWP 114 "ZMQbg/Reaper" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  17   LWP 115 "ZMQbg/IO/0" 0x00007f1b8850bbb7 in ?? ()
  18   LWP 116 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b884febf9 in ?? ()
  19   LWP 117 "grpc_global_tim" 0x00007f1b88505839 in ?? ()
  20   LWP 118 "python3.8" 0x00007f1b881db6d6 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
```

**I'd like to see the python code.**

the others inforamtion:

1)I was installed python3.8-gdb.
The progarm of python3.8 is stripped.

2)I use another gdb to debug it, command is
`gdb --pid 97`, and get the message 'warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified'

```
Attaching to process 97
[New LWP 100]
[New LWP 101]
[New LWP 102]
[New LWP 103]
[New LWP 104]
[New LWP 105]
[New LWP 106]
[New LWP 107]
[New LWP 108]
[New LWP 109]
[New LWP 110]
[New LWP 111]
[New LWP 112]
[New LWP 113]
[New LWP 114]
[New LWP 115]
[New LWP 116]
[New LWP 117]
[New LWP 118]

warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
0x00007f1b8850ca66 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Do you have an executable program named `python3.8-dbg` that you can run instead of `python3.8` ?

Comment: python3.8-dbg is the symbol of python3.8, but I was installed python3.8-dbg , the execute program "python3.8" is replaced

Comment: This problem has been solved.
It is a problem with python programs.
My program is a service, using the original Python program. When I install the package python3.8-dbg and then start my program, the problem is resolved.